# django model relation definition

Tags: django-models, foreign-keys, database-relations

Let say I have 3 models: A, B and C with the following relations.

A can have many B and many C.

B can have many C

Is the following correct:

```
class A(models.Model):
  ...

class B(models.Model):
  ...
  a = models.ForeignKey(A)

class C(models.Model):
  ...
  a = models.ForeignKey(A)
  b = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

Or is there a more efficient way of doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes. It's all correct, I have nothing to say. (On a side note, shouldn't that be `models.ForeignKey(model_name)` ?)